# Use both functional Programming and Spring annotations - Resilience4j

Tags: resilience4j

I am using resilience4j Library for fault tolerance with Spring Boot.
I want to maintain resilience4j configuration in application.yml file.

I want to use resilience 4j annotations as it helps to keep the business logic clean.

But in cases where the annotations do not work(like AOP does not allow calling methods of the same class and not being able to annotate Spring data repository methods) I want to use the functional programming approach .

For the configuration given in application.yml file , how do I create CircuitBreaker and Retry beans in my Spring boot applications so that I can decorate calls with high order functional programming in some scenarios and use annotations in other.

My current configuration:

```
resilience4j:
  retry:
    configs:
      default:
        max-retry-attempts: 3
        wait-duration: 5s
        retry-exception-predicate: com.example.resilience.predicate.RetryExceptionPredicate
        retry-exceptions:
          - java.io.IOException
          - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    instances:
      ierp-test:
        base-config: default
```

Comment: just a note, anything you want "processed" by the predicate (specified by "retry-exception-predicate", should NOT be in your "retry-exceptions" list.   see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75655161/214977

Answer (score 0):

Just inject the CircuitBreakerRegistry into you bean.

Answer (score 0):

Such configuration will wrap circuitbreaker over retry

```
resilience4j:
  retry:
    retry-aspect-order: 2
    instances:
      myRertry:
    ...
circuitbreaker:
    circuit-breaker-aspect-order: 1
    instances:
      myCircuitBreaker:
    ...
```