# How to configure the retryOnResultPredicate in resilience4j?

Tags: resilience4j

I want to set failAfterMaxAttempts to true to get the MaxRetriesExceededException at the end of max retry. According to the doc we need to set the predicate for  retryOnResultPredicate with failAfterMaxAttempts. Can someone help with the example config ?  So the retryOnResultPredicate should evaluate the response http status.

```
resilience4j.retry:
    configs:
        default:
            maxAttempts: 3
            waitDuration: 100
            failAfterMaxAttempts: true
            retryOnResultPredicate:
            retryExceptions:
                - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
                - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                - java.io.IOException
            ignoreExceptions:
                - io.github.robwin.exception.BusinessException
```

Answer (score 2):

Setup your predicate. (written in kotlin)

```
package com.myapp.resilience.config
import java.util.function.Predicate

class ConditionalPredicate : Predicate<MyException> {
    /** For purposes of Retry, if it returns true, it will retry this exception */
    override fun test(t: MyException): Boolean =  = t.statusCode != 404
}
```

Then add to your config (example only):

```
resilience4j.retry:
    configs:
        default:
            retryExceptionPredicate: com.myapp.resilience.config.ConditionalPredicate
```

Helpful note, the Predicate exception you build - in this example (MyException) should be excluded from the `retryExceptions` block in the config. If you have it there too, your predicate will not be called.

I had found similar examples [here](https://reflectoring.io/retry-with-springboot-resilience4j/) for ResultPredicate
And also info [here](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry) about the config options.

It is definitely not documented very well at this point (3/2023)

Comment: I'd upvote 3X if I could.  One for answer.  Two for including the import statements.  and Three for this code comment : "/** For purposes of Retry, if it returns true, it will retry this exception */"   Thanks!  Make that 4X.  "(MyException) should be excluded from retryExceptions".